# Problems with isolated scope and bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, javascript-databinding

I try to build directive in which i want to change model on clicking by element. Some sort of checkbox...
Here is my code

```
mainApp.directive('subCategory', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            model: '=?ngModel'
        },
        link : function(scope, element){

            scope.model = true;
            element.click(function () {

            if (element.hasClass('active')) {
                element.removeClass('active');
                scope.model = false;
            } else {
                element.addClass('active');
                scope.model = true;
            }

         });
        }
    } 
});
```

Than i try to $watch group of this checkboxes in parent controller by watching object which contains ng-model properties of all checkboxes.

```
mainApp.controller('Filter',['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.data = {}

$scope.$watchCollection('data', function(newNames, oldNames) {
  console.log('changed');
});

}]);
```

When i define property by `scope.model = true;` it works and watching works, but when i change `scope.model` on click in some reasons it doesn't affect `data` object and watch doesn't work. 
Can someone tell me why?
Thanks!

Comment: Using `ng-model` as an attribute instantiates the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). That controller is likely fighting the custom directive. Use of the `ng-` prefix is reserved for core directives. For more information, see [AngularJS Wiki - Best Practices](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Best-Practices).

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg! You are right!

Answer (score 0):

In your directive change

```
 scope: {
        model: '=?ngModel'
    },
```

To

```
  scope: {
        model: '=ngModel'
    },
```

as mentioned above when you pass ngModel to link function that is when you declare

```
 require:'?ngModel'
```